# Alternatives to "which is good because"?

Tags: synonyms

I'm currently trying to translate from English into a foreign language. Unfortunately I can't find any way to translate "It's 50 km away, **which is good because** there's not much here", so if anybody has any alternative phrases to "which is good because", they'd be greatly appreciated - I'm hoping that alternative phrases may be easier to translate.

Comment: 'which has the advantage of', 'which has the benefits of'.

Comment: What's 50km away?  Is that considered close or far away?

Answer (score 2):

"It's 50 km away, ***thankfully***, because there's not much here."

(Assuming that in context, 50 km is a relatively short distance, thus offering the speaker that which is not in abundance "here".)